# wrf.exe:libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file:

Tags: c, fortran, mpi, linker-errors

I have configured and compiled WRF and WPS successfully.
and then ran ungrib.exe and geogrid and metgrid.exe and real.exe.

When I run wrf.exe on more than one node using MPI it gives the following errors. (although a simple command ./wrf.exe is running on a single node but runtime error segmentation fault)

```
~/WRF/test/em_real$ mpiexec -np 4 -hostfile ~/hostfile ./wrf.exe 
./wrf.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
./wrf.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
./wrf.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
./wrf.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

although if you see in following terminal output libgfortran.so.3 is available in the system. (I am working on a my university cluster on which i am not having root/sudo access)

```
anikett:~/WRF/test/em_real$ locate libgfortran
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgfortran.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgfortran.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgfortran.spec
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgfortranbegin.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.4.0.0
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/.libs/libgfortran-ed201abd.so.3.0.0
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/.libs/libgfortran-ed201abd.so.3.0.0
/usr/share/doc/libgfortran-5-dev
/usr/share/doc/libgfortran3
/usr/share/doc/libgfortran4
```

even though I have followed all the exact process that is mentioned in compiling WRF page.
gfortran is installed.

```
anikett:~/WRF/test/em_real$ which gfortran
/usr/bin/gfortran
```

and MPICH installation is also correct because I have ran some MPI programs(Both C and Fortran) on different nodes from one node (using mpiexec) successfully.
I have been stuck at this for couple of days now.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Is gfortran also installed on the compute nodes? Are you able to run your code on the master node? What is your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on the master node? What is your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on the compute nodes?

Comment: Yes @VladimirF sir, gfortran is installed all the other compute nodes. 
if by master node you mean the node at which i will execute mpiexec command.
In master node if i run ./wrf.exe then runtime error - segmentation fault.(probably due to memory insufficient for running wrf).
My $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 

echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/users/project/anikett/mpich-install/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

Comment: Is that `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` also set on the copute nodes? Try `mpiexec -np 4 -hostfile ~/hostfile echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Try compiling some simple Fortran hello world and run it through mpiexec. The hello world program does not have to be MPI-aware.

Comment: I@VladimirF I have already done that ( i think i have mentioned that in post as well "MPICH installation is also correct because I have ran some MPI programs(Both C and Fortran) on different nodes from one node (using mpiexec) successfully" ) and yes $LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set on all compute nodes. 

I am actually working on a shared cluster where if i made any change in my space it is already get reflected on all the other nodes. (on which i login to or ssh to)

Comment: Is WRF trying to do some dodgy stuff on its own? In that case some WRF support forum would be a place to ask.